# Google Analytics Custom Dimension usage with user scope

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, web-analytics

I'm planning to set a custom dimension with user scope for any visitor that goes into any page of certain directory in a website to classify users into two groups:

- Visitors that have visited (ever) the section in mentioned directory.
- Visitors that haven't visited (ever) the section in the mentioned directory.

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374550/how-can-i-get-results-for-a-dimension-custom-variables-where-the-value-is-not) talking about a similar matter and it states that google analytics' custom dimensions do not have default values so a solution to this is to always send the default value and only change it when the criteria is met but this comes into conflict (according to me) with google analytics [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828) about how user scoped variables get their value: in short the last hit gets saved.

So I was thinking of the following approach, only set the custom variable with user scope when users visit any page within this directory and in the reporting use the include/exclude functionality to separate these two groups but I'm afraid I might be missing something.

- Will this approach work considering that if a hit on this custom dimension does not happen google analytics won't consider it in the aggregations?
- How can I set the custom variable to catch this users but dont overwrite it if they visit a page outside this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach would work but you should bear in mind that any user who hasn't been assigned a value for this custom dimension will be excluded from any the reports that you do that have that use that dimension.

I think you'd be better off setting a cookie that will track if the user has ever been to the pages in question. That way you could always send a value. Below I've borrowed the cookie functions off w3schools.com as I'm not accustomed to javascript cookies. I'm sure you could find a shorter way to do it.

```
//Cookie functons borrowed from w3schools.com
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

//start of Standard code goes here
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

//now check for cookie value
var everBeen = getCookie('everBeen');
if(everBeen != 'hasBeen'){
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    if(path.indexOf('/requireddirectory') != -1){
        everBeen = 'hasBeen';
    } else{
        everBeen = 'neverBeen';
    }
}

setCookie('everBeen',everBeen,1461);

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  everBeen
});
```